# jquery cycle plugin caption not functioning

Tags: jquery, cycle, caption

I've sorted this issue out now

If you're having trouble with the captions on cycle you can actually achieve them by simply wrapping the img in

```
<span></span>
```

tags and either using those to hold the text - or make

```
<p></p>
```

tags to hold the text and apply css to style them.

If you want to have them appear over the img then css that effect with z index or something...

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo but you have an extra `</div>` in there

Comment: thanks, it's from an opening div tag that comes before the slideshow starts; a container.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#caption').html(this.title);
```

Is placing the title *element* for the page into the caption tag. What you want is the alt (or title) *attribute* of each image element, so try this.attr, so something like .....

```
$('#caption').html(this.attr("alt"));
```

or if you want to use the title attribute, just replace alt in the above with "title"

[This link covers attr in more detail](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: thanks, but it still isn't working. It doesn't break the script but it doesn't display anything either. I've looked through the information in the linked page, but I am unfamiliar with js and jquery